# Crash report from a user. How can I solve this crash?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I uploadet my app yesterday and now a user sended me a crash report.
Here is the report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.aaron.waller.angelasoundboard/com.aaron.waller.angelasoundboard.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.pause()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4591)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4550)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4525)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:222)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1806)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.pause()' on a null object reference
    at com.aaron.waller.angelasoundboard.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:145)
    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:7033)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1339)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4577)
    ... 10 more
```

The onPause() method is doing problems, is that right?
What can I do now?

Comment: You are clearly calling pause() method of the MediaPlayer before it is initialized; just post your MainActivity code - look at line 145

Comment: You could post your code.

Comment: @Eenvincible in Line 145 is the onPause() method.     ´@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mp.pause();
        super.onPause();

    }´

Comment: Here is my MainActivity.java http://pastebin.com/Kt8cCEPa I souroundet the line 145 with big Z's so you can find it easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the same check you use in the other situations:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Without the `== true` it would be even better :)